# Android date popup, range

Tags: android, datepicker, range, max

I have a date picker that allows a user to select a date, by default this lets you change the year higher and higher to infinite or something, but I want to confine the user to a maximum year. Such as only 2 years from now.

`new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay)`

How do I set the max date within that function?  I'm sure I can do a "if date > 2014 , then show a toast message and show the datepicker again until they select a proper date" but I would prefer to just not let the date picker function go above a certain year.

Insight appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **OnDateChangedListener** to DatePicker Object and then override the

```
@Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

//Do the check here for the year

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I only have the DatePickerDialog object and a OnDateSetListener object , how do I incorporate a datepicker into this arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

Create a datepicker and add that view to your dialog layout, If you want any custom behaviour then you need a custom date picker, override the `onDateChanged()` to behave as per your need.

If just you need is to restrict the maximum date of the date picker, use `setMaxDate(long maxDate)` for the datepicker.

you can use `getDatePicker()` on the dialog to get the instance of the it inside the dialog.

refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html
and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html
for more info.